# when i update oh-my-zsh i got a error.how do i fix it?

Tags: shell

```
[oh-my-zsh] Insecure completion-dependent directories detected: 
drwxr-xr-x  6 501  admin  204  3  2  2016 /usr/local/share/zsh 
drwxr-xr-x  8 501  admin  272 10 10  2016 /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions 
[oh-my-zsh] For safety, completions will be disabled until you manually fix all 
[oh-my-zsh] insecure directory permissions and ownership and restart oh-my-zsh. 
[oh-my-zsh] See the above list for directories with group or other writability.
```

[image]

Answer (score 38):

Try to change .oh-my-zsh/ permissions:

```
➜ sudo chmod -R 755 ~/.oh-my-zsh
```

If it doesn't help, try:

```
➜ chmod 755 /usr/local/share/zsh
➜ chmod 755 /usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions
```

Comment: this `sudo chmod -R 755 ~/.oh-my-zsh` works for me, thanks

Comment: second one worked for me on mac big sur, thanks.

Answer (score 8):

For people who uses MacOs with prebuilt zsh and installed oh-my-zsh on top of that (similar error)

```
compaudit | xargs chmod g-w,o-w
```

This might fix it.

Comment: This command is stated in the docs. It works correctly on macOS Catalina https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/blob/de2395c678228a5bc6b22711d2bc1b17797d639d/lib/compfix.zsh#L37

Comment: I have no idea what this does, but it worked for me. If anyone could explain that would be great. Tks!

Comment: I don't understand why this is happening, but this command worked for me too.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with the most recent ohmyzsh update. One of the directories under .oh-my-zsh had 777 permissions. Changing that directory to 755 fixed my issue. I don't know if that will help you because those folders already appear to have 755 permissions. Try navigating to those folders and checking the permissions manually.

Answer (score 0):

I've change the permission, but that's not enough to make it work, so I also need to change ownership of the directory

```
chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/share/zsh
```

OR

```
chown -R <USERNAME> /usr/local/share/zsh
```

This way it works for me, and I hope it will also helpful to you too.